# Catching functors using SFINAE in structure partial specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

For some complicated reason, I want to convert any supported type T (coming from a template) to a list of types I have chosen. For this, I tried using a template structure named "Convert". For example:

```
Convert<short>::type should be int
Convert<int>::type should be int
Convert<char>::type should be int
Convert<float>::type should be double
Convert<double>::type should be double
Convert<const char*>::type should be std::string
Convert<std::string>::type should be std::string
etc.
```

Those above are easy to implement using template specialisation. But there is one case that is causing problems :

```
Convert<T>::type where T is a functor should be T
```

To handle this, I think I have to use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) but I can't manage to make it compile.

The code below gives me "[partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad94bhc0(VS.80).aspx)" (ie. writing "Convert" is forbidden) :

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::operator())>
struct Convert<T>       { typedef T type; };
```

And this one gives me "[template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6z5yfwk(VS.80).aspx)" (ie. it thinks that T is not used) :

```
template<typename T>
struct Convert<typename std::enable_if<std::is_function<typename T::operator()>::value,T>::type>
 { typedef T type; };
```

I have no idea of what to do, all my attempts result in one of the two errors above.

EDIT: I would like to catch other generic things using the same model, so I can't just write "typedef T type" in the non-specialized structure.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "catch other generic things"?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "a functor". Is a function also good? Or is it only function objects? If so, then anything with `operator()` overloaded? Or derived from `std::function_object`? A specific number of parameters?

Comment: Examples: "Convert<T>::type is int if T is convertible to an int", or "Convert<T>::type is ... if T has a begin and an end function", etc.

Comment: @sbi: In the example above I tried to catch function objects with an operator() (any number of parameter) ; I can handle functions with another specialisation

Comment: @Tomaka17: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/257382#257382? (link changed)

Comment: @sbi: yeah but this is just a replacement for std::is_function ; even if I have an `has_helloworld` class, `Convert<std::enable_if<has_helloworld<T>::result,T>::type>` would fail to compile ; not because of has_helloworld but because of this Convert specialisation not allowed

Comment: @Tomaka17: Wouldn't `std::is_function<typename T::operator()>::value` have to be spelled `typename std::is_function<T::operator()>::value` instead?

Comment: @sbi: I get an error if I don't specify typename here, but anyway `std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::operator())>::value` doesn't work either

Comment: (sorry, misread your comment) No because std::enable_if expected a bool, not a type

Comment: @Tomaka17: Oh, I overlooked that. Anyway, `T::operator()` should certainly not have a `typename`. __Edit:__ I now see that jpalecek has said the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the first approach, but to make it work, you'll have to

Declare the master template with one unused template-argument:

```
template <class T, class = void> Convert;
```

Add a `void` parameter to all specializations of the template you use now.

Define your "functor specialization" like this:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_function<typename T::operator()>::value,void>::type>
```

That means you make the second argument `void` if it is a functor (so it matches the default template argument) or nonexisting if it isn't.

BTW why do you use `typename` in `typename T::operator()`? AFAIK, `operator()` is not a type.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Apparently I don't even need to add `void` to my other specialisations. However the compiler uses the unspecialized structure for the moment, I'll try to make it work.

Comment: You're maybe right for the typename, anyway I tried several things like `std::enable_if<!std::is_void<decltype(&T::operator())>::value>::type` which I think is correct

Comment: `Convert<T, typename std::enable_if<true,void>::type>` is working, so there must be a problem in my condition

Comment: The code in my second commentary works on g++ but not on MSVC++, however I made it work on both compiler by creating a "IsFunctor" type inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/257382#257382 Thanks